# HTTP 404 - JBoss AS 7 - Eclipse Juno - OpenShift App

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, openshift

I'm not new to Java and Web-development but very very new to JBoss, Maven and OpenShift (Redhat) - I want to deploy a basic `Hello, World` from Eclipse.

I created a new **OpenShift** and **JBoss AS 7** app in eclipse, it auto-configured all the maven stuff (To which I don't have much of an idea). I ran the **index.html** without any errors - It opened fine on `localhost:8080/app-name`

But when I navigate to `localhost:8080/app-name/servlet-name` it gives me a **HTTP 404**.

Here's my directories:

[image]

And my `servlets` from **WEB-INF/web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Auth</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>co.suhas.live.Auth</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Auth</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Auth</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What is it that I'm missing and not doing?
Thanks.

Comment: checked the logs? does the resulting .war look ok, do you have war configured in maven pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting and cleaning Eclipse seemed to fix the issue! Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Applications on OpenShift don't bind to localhost. They bind to OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP and are exposed externally on OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS:80.